# Default value assigned to decimal?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to figure out why the amount value is not showing as empty when no value is entered for the currencyfield.  How do I see what the default value is for @state var amount: Decimal?

I think if I can solve for this I can rework the modifiers for the Text value - "Balance"

```
              @State var amount: Decimal?

               ZStack(alignment: .leading){

               CurrencyField("",value: Binding(get: {
                    mortgageAmount.map { NSDecimalNumber(decimal: $0) }
                }, set: { number in mortgageAmount = number?.decimalValue}))

               Text("Balance")
                   .foregroundColor(String(describing: amount).isEmpty ? Color(Design.TextDark!) : Color(Design.accent!))
               .font(Font.custom(Design.PrimaryFont, size: 16))
               .offset(y: String(describing: amount).isEmpty ? 0 :-25)
               .scaleEffect(String(describing: amount).isEmpty ? 1: 0.8, anchor: .leading)


           }
```

Comment: Please include a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
.scaleEffect( amount == nil ? 1: 0.8, anchor: .leading)
```

`String(describing: amount)` will be equal to `"nil"` so it will not be an empty